# Flutter - how to update web manifest.json version to match the version in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I wish to change my version in the pubspec.yaml, and then have that reflected throughout the application targets, specifically including flutter web. However, if I update the pubspec and rebuild the web, my "version" in the manifest.json file does not get changed. Is there any approach I can do to make this change with the pubspec.yaml file?